# How to make images available in Properties.Resources

Tags: c#, image, properties

I have found some code I want to implement in my project.

In the code the author references an image as:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.delete;
```

Where delete is an image of an unknown type.

How would I be able to achieve this?

I have the images I want to use and can convert to any format.

Comment: What do mean by unknown type? If you don't know the type, you can convert it, I guess

Comment: It just does not state in the tutorial what file type the image is. The code does not reference any file extension (it is typed exactly as I shown in the code example).

Comment: Are you sure, that it's a file actually? Maybe it's base64 string with image content or path to file with image? Btw, are you targeting WinForms of WPF?

Comment: In the tutorial he has as screenshot of the image showing in his app. It is a red cross. It appears next to a Text Box if the text entered in the Text Box does not meet the regex criteria. WinForms.

Comment: Anyway, you should what is the exact return value of this property `Properties.Resources.delete`

Comment: Figured it out. Needs to be a bitmap. Then drag and drop to the Properties Resources screen.

Comment: png works too. Good, as needed the transparency.